# Passing parameters to helper in Meteor's dynamic templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I realise that this has been brought up before, and that `Template.dynamic` isn't designed to take in a parameter if its template parameter is a helper.

But here is what I would like to do:

```js
// a global helper that composites the template's name using domain-specific and global parameters
Template.registerHelper('templateName', function (name) {
  return name + Session.get('someVariable');
});
```

```html
<!-- use case: a template calling two dynamic ones -->
<template name="someTemplate">
  <div class="some-class">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=templateName 'title' }}
  </div>
  <div class="another-class">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=templateName 'content' }}
  </div>
</template>
```

This pattern is extremely DRY and it avoids having to set up nested conditionals and rewrite quasi-identical templates each with minimal changes.

Right now, I've got this:

```js
Template.registerHelper('templateName', function () {
  var dt = this.dName || Template.parentData().dName;
  return dName + Session.get('someVariable'));
});
```

```html
<template name="someTemplate">
  {{> segment dName="title"}}
  {{> segment dName="content"}}
</template>

<template name="segment">
  <div class="some-class">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=templateName }}
  </div>
</template>
```

It works, but it isn't ideal, because;

- confusion-prone need to include the parameter for the dynamic template's name in the parent template's call
- only ever being allowed one `Template.dynamic` per template due to one parameter, leading to scalability issues
- putting the `dName` parameter in the template's data context is mixed in with local data, requiring the hacky check whether it's accessible in the current one or the parent's
- any further complexity in the DOM requires lots of nested conditionals for parameters or many slightly different static templates, leading to bloat

Are there plans to add this functionality? Am I going about this the wrong way? Did anyone else run into these issues?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to doing this with {{with}}.  See here:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/pass-argument-to-helper-in-template-dynamic-call/3971